# Why couldn't they live with different appearances in "What happened to Monday"?

Tags: plot-explanation, what-happened-to-monday

In the movie "What Happened to Monday" the grandpa was able to tweak and get 1 (original) and 6 (knockoff) bracelets for each of the sisters.

If he could do that why couldn't he just ask each of the sisters to alter their appearances a bit, have them leave at different times (apartment monitoring) and have them live their lives everyday instead of one day a week? They would still be registered as single child due to the tweaking grandpa did right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because every day, they have to use the bracelet to access transportation and cross zones.  Those accesses would be tracked.  What are the authorities going to think when a supposed single person enters the subway seven times, a few minutes apart each time, and then leaves the subway having gone to seven different places?  Is working seven different jobs, at the same time?

Comment: they would be A,B,C,D,E,F,G (seven different names), seven different appearances and working seven separate places. they all wouldn't be Karen Settman right ? so wouldn't that work ? And they have 7 bracelets - not one, so that could be achievable right ?

Comment: i agree with your answer .. BUT i mean lets assume im the grandpa.. I would get them registered (illegally or legally, hes a man of both means) under 7 different names and get them to use different disguises (as in the movie some of them look different owing to the hair and all) and send them off (to school or later when im dead the work etc.) this has been bugging me. they dont have to be registered as siblings right ! am i missing something ?

Comment: Getting a bracelet cloned is probably hard, but only relies on something you already have in your possession, and, to be honest, the government probably doesn’t care much about.  Defining a new person would require obtaining six other bracelets, each of which would have to be different, and registering them as separate people, probably by breaking into many, many databases.  And that, specifically, is what the system is dedicated to preventing.  It’s the difference between cloning a credit card and creating a fake, working credit card.  The first is doable; the second one, almost impossible.